# Facebook Bot: Message Mentioner

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a bot that would message anyone who mentions (@PageName) it. I have set up the mention webhook for my bot so that whenever anyone mentions my page in a comment or post, I receive a notification. Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't make it easy to message the person who mentioned my page, since there are different page IDs and messenger IDs. I am able to fetch the user ID from the mention by fetching the `from` field from the graph API, but is it possible to convert this user ID to a messenger ID so that I may actually message the user?

Comment: are you sure it´s even possible to send a message to someone who only mentioned a page, but did not interact with your bot yet? i am pretty sure that´s not possible, would be weird if it would be.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have included that the user who mentioned me **has** previously interacted with the page. The user sends a message to the bot, and from that, I get a `sender_id` but the problem is that the user ID returned by the comment's `from` field is different from the sender_id. Is it possible to map the user ID returned by the comment to the sender_id returned by a message?